# Global variable for Postman in documentation does not work

Tags: postman, postman-native-app

I have defined a 'Global' variable for 'postman' to be used under the postman's documentation.

However after loading the documentation it looks like the variable is not coming through at all. I can see what its assigned to but not the actual expected value is there.

If I set this variable under a particular environment then it works fine.

Is there anything preventing global variables to work in documentation? has anyone else faced this same issue?

p.s I know variables in lower levels take precedence so I have removed them from all environments and only have them set in Global. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Are you able to share any images of what you're seeing?

Comment: sensitive information in there still i'm afraid. Will have to strip them out. I think i may go down a route of defining a separate environment for documentation or just use the one for production. its very odd @DannyDainton

Comment: The functionality isn't there to be able to use global variables for the documentation. Using the Environment or Collection level ones would be the other options.

Comment: Thanks, I guessed that might be the case, It is a shame considering it would have fitted our case perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

based on answer from @dannydainton above who works for Postman:

*The functionality isn't there to be able to use global variables for
the documentation. Using the Environment or Collection level ones
would be the other options.*